# Двойной вызов деструктора

Tags: c++, строки, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой двойного вызова деструктора (деструктор вызывается 2 раза подряд для 1 и того же объекта).

Вот вызывающий код в main() :

```
CharRow row(4);
CharRow row2(3);

cin >> row;
cin >> row2;

CharRow temp = row - row2;
```

CharRow - класс, который содержит указатель на строку.

Проблема возникает в перегруженном operator- () :

```
        CharRow CharRow::operator- (CharRow& row2)
{
    int row1Length = this->getRowCurrentLength();
    int row2Length = row2.getRowCurrentLength();
    CharRow tempRow(row1Length - row2Length);
    char source[row1Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < row1Length; i++)
    {
        source[i] = this->ptr[i];
    }

    char* tmpStr;
    tmpStr = strstr(source, row2.ptr);

    //if row2 is not substring for row1
    if (tmpStr == NULL)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    strcpy(tmpStr, tmpStr + row2Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < row1Length - row2Length; i++)
    {
        tempRow.ptr[i] = source[i];
    }

    return tempRow;
}
```

после строки

```
return tempRow;
```

вызывается копирующий конструктор:

```
CharRow::CharRow(const CharRow &obj){
    this->ROW_MAX_LENGTH = obj.ROW_MAX_LENGTH;
    this->ptr = obj.ptr;
}
```

После конструктора копирования вызывается деструктор :

```
CharRow::~CharRow(){
   //ptr = NULL;
        delete [] ptr;
}
```

А затем этот деструктор вызывается еще раз и происходит критическое завершение программы.( т.к. деструктор пытается удалить null pointer (как я понимаю).

Помогите дойти до полного понимания проблемы и подсказать как правильно выйти из этой ситуации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом предложении

```
CharRow temp = row - row2;
```

создается временный объект. Во-первых, этот временный объект может содержать копию указателя `ptr` объекта `row`.

```
CharRow CharRow::operator- (CharRow& row2)
{
    // ...
    //if row2 is not substring for row1
    if (tmpStr == NULL)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    //...
}
```

Во-вторых, копия этого же указателя присваивается создаваемому объекту `temp`. И все это благодаря тому, что ваш конструктор копирования просто присваивает значение данного указателя одного объекта другому другому объекту.

```
CharRow::CharRow(const CharRow &obj){
    this->ROW_MAX_LENGTH = obj.ROW_MAX_LENGTH;
    this->ptr = obj.ptr;
}
```

Так что не исключена даже ситуация, когда одна и та же память будет удаляться не только два раза, но и три раза! А все потому, что все три объекта содержат указатели с одним и тем же значением, которые указывают на одну и ту же область памяти.

Когда вы сами вручную выделяете память, то вам надо делать "глубокое копирование", то есть не просто присваивать один указатель другому, а создавать новую область памяти и туда копировать данные так, чтобы каждый указатель указывал на свою собственную выделенную память.

Поэтому вам в явном виде нужно определить по крайней мере конструктор копирования, копирующий оператор присваивания и деструктор.

Имейте в виду, что стандарт языка C++ не поддерживает массивы переменной длины, а потому объявления, подобные данному

```
int row1Length = this->getRowCurrentLength();
// ... 
char source[row1Length];
```

являются не совместимыми со стандартом C++.

Кроме того оператор `operator -` у вас скорей всего имеет неопределенное поведение, так как вы используете функции для работы со строками, а объявленный массив, скорей всего, у вас не содержит завершающего нуля.

Comment: А можно совет, как можно заменить 
`int row1Length = this->getRowCurrentLength();`

Comment: @ReturnedVoid А зачем вам заменять? Просто не нужно пользоваться данным массивом.

Comment: Я этот массив использую как временный и мне же нужно как-то узнать его размер...

Comment: Изменил CopyConstructor на вот такой код :
   `CharRow::CharRow(const CharRow &obj){ 

        this->ROW_MAX_LENGTH = obj.ROW_MAX_LENGTH;  

        ptr = new char[ROW_MAX_LENGTH];  
        for(int i = 0; i < ROW_MAX_LENGTH; i++){  
            this->ptr[i] = obj.ptr[i];  
        }  
    }` 
Проблема исчезла, но все же вот в 1 ситуации все равно возникает (

Comment: @ReturnedVoid Что за 1 ситуация? Вам еще надо копирующий оператор присваивания написать.

Comment: как-то возникла, но теперь все хорошо. Копирующий оператор присваивания я давно написал. Он у меня мало отличается от теперишнего конструктора копирования. Извините, не знаю как правильно код в комментариях вставлять.

Comment: Вот operator=() :
     `CharRow CharRow::operator=(CharRow& row2){ 


        int row2Length = row2.getRowCurrentLength();

        this->ROW_MAX_LENGTH = row2.ROW_MAX_LENGTH;

        for(int i = 0; i < row2Length; i++){
            this->ptr[i] = row2.ptr[i];
        }<br/>
        return *this;
    }`

Comment: @ReturnedVoid Он не корректно написан. закрывайте этот вопрос и задавайте следующий: как правильно написать копирующий оператор присваивания.

Comment: Спасибо ! вы очень помогли, в книгах почитаю что не так с operator=() у меня )

Comment: @ReturnedVoid Вы должны освобождать память, которой владеет объект, прежде чем выделять новую память.

Comment: Последнее сообщение относиться к конструктору копирования ?? потому что в operator=() я новой памяти не выделяю.

Comment: @ReturnedVoid Если у вас память всегда имеет фиксированный размер, то, да, действительно, не надо ее удалять, а можно использовать под новую строку.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема ваша тут:

```
CharRow::CharRow(const CharRow &obj){
    this->ROW_MAX_LENGTH = obj.ROW_MAX_LENGTH;
    this->ptr = obj.ptr;
}
```

По всей видимости `ptr` указывает на динамически выделенную память (иначе вы бы не прибегали к `delete` :)). Вы копируете **указатель**, а не содержимое памяти, так что у вас в двух объектах одинаковый указатель на одно и то же место в памяти. Который вы в результате как минимум удаляете дважды, или, например, удалив один раз, пытаетесь работать с ним.

Копируйте **содержимое** - выделите новую память и скопируйте туда данные из памяти, на которую указывает другой объект.

P.S. Кстати, `delete` нулевого указателя - вполне разрешенная операция, `delete` проверяет указатель на равенство нулю.